# multi-language .htaccess redirect to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a multilanguage website (spanish, english, french) in PHP which main's language is english.

If `$_SESSION['idm']` is set to 'en' it loads a file with the translations.

I want to set it up this way:

**if the user language is spanish**

`www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` -> `es.mydomain.com`

`www.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3` -> `es.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3`

**if user language is french**

`www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com` -> `fr.mydomain.com`

`www.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3` -> `fr.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3`

**if not any of the above**

`www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com` -> `en.mydomain.com`

`www.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3` -> `en.mydomain.com/video.php?id=3`

How do I do that, and, is this good SEO wise?

Comment: I don't think this is doable using .htaccess ... you need to do it from PHP.

Comment: @Aziz how would you do it in PHP then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in PHP:

```
// check if the current domain is the generic one
$req_domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
if ($req_domain == 'www.mydomain.com' || $req_domain == 'mydomain.com') {
  $subdomains = array ('fr' => 'fr.mydomain.com',
                       'es' => 'es.mydomain.com',
                       'en' => 'en.mydomain.com');


  // get the language from the session variable (if set), or use default
  $lang = 'en'; // default language
  if ( isset($_SESSION['idm']) && isset($subdomains[$_SESSION['idm']]) )
    $lang = $_SESSION['idm']; // selected language


  // redirect while maintaining the complete request URI
  header('Location: http://' . $domains[$lang] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks that was very useful! I wish I could vote you positively :)

Comment: so each domain will have a whole set of code ? i.e each sub domain will include all the files ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better for SEO than your current session based method which hides the language variations from the search engines.

One slight alteration would be to keep the default language (en) on the main domain.

To make it work best:

Ensure on page links are relative so you don't cause redirects on every click.

Add hreflang meta data to the pages to indicate where the translations are.

Don't force people into a language. Make sure they can easily change.